# How to manipulate data ERA5-land in R

Tags: r, raster, netcdf, temperature, era5

This is the first time I work with the spatial data so I really need your help.

I tried to download data ERA5-land monthly from [this](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-land-monthly-means?tab=overview) using python (with the format netcdf.zip). I chose the subregion that can cover France. After that I tried to read the data in R by the following code:

```
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

ncfile <- nc_open(filepath)
print(ncfile)
```

and I get the result like that: (I list variable t2m for example, the others have the same discription).

```
33 variables (excluding dimension variables):
        
        short t2m[longitude,latitude,expver,time]   
            scale_factor: 0.000759505975281538
            add_offset: 277.460679817325
            _FillValue: -32767
            missing_value: -32767
            units: K
            long_name: 2 metre temperature
        ..... 

     4 dimensions:
        longitude  Size:151 
            units: degrees_east
            long_name: longitude
        latitude  Size:100 
            units: degrees_north
            long_name: latitude
        expver  Size:2 
            long_name: expver
        time  Size:886 
            units: hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0
            long_name: time
            calendar: gregorian

    2 global attributes:
        Conventions: CF-1.6
        history: 2023-11-21 15:03:18 GMT by grib_to_netcdf-2.24.0: /opt/ecmwf/eccodes/bin/grib_to_netcdf -S param -o /cache/tmp/7a615d9b-759a-4ab0-a842-c978c79c8850-adaptor.mars.internal-1700578884.4900465-17448-6-tmp.nc /cache/tmp/7a615d9b-759a-4ab0-a842-c978c79c8850-adaptor.mars.internal-1700573425.5042555-17448-4-tmp.grib
```

> (1) I don't know why the number of missing value equals to the number of fill value? I checked it and it turns out if I filtered expver = 2 than I get all NA, indeed, in the expver 1 there also exists NAs.
> when I tried to plot the data using this code:

```
t2m_var <- ncvar_get(ncfile, "t2m")
t2m_v1 <- t2m_var[,,1,880]  #longitude, latitude, expver, time
t2m_v2 <- t2m_var[,,2,880]
t2m_slice <- t2m_v1
index <- is.na(t2m_slice)
t2m_slice[index] <- t2m_v2[index]
t2m_raster <- raster(t2m_slice, xmn=min(lon), xmx=max(lon), ymn=min(lat), ymx=max(lat), crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```

> (2) I got a weird picture where there are many empty space that corresponding to NA (it shouldn't be like that? because ERA5-data cover all the territory?)
> [Temperature of air at 2m above the surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6EcA.png)
> I'm thinking that did I miss something when working with this data.

(3) Can you help me to figure out which step was wrong and the way to fix it?
Thank you so much !

Comment: In addition to France, what date of data did you download? i.e. it would help if we were talking about the same data that I can download from Copernicus. But I don't think you've done anything wrong per se. There are potentially environmental factors, depending on the satellite instrument, that preclude measurement and result in NA or -32767 values. Think clouds cover, which your 'white' areas look like, whereas the gradient of measurable temperatures follow a predictable lowering with elevation into the Pyrennes. This thinking assumes the instruments are not cloud penetrating.Welcome to SOF.

Comment: @Chris I'm sure you are trying to help but pretty much everything you wrote is wrong

Comment: I look forward to your comments then the learn therefrom.

Comment: @Chris I just posted my answer. Environmental factors, satellite instruments or cloud cover have nothing to do with the issues presented, nor with ERA5 data in general.

Answer (score 1):

You have two separate problems and you have to solve them individually because they are not related or compounding.

First of all, you have a mix of ERA5 and ERA5T data, with the latter type being the "experimental" data from the most recent period. Data is initially released as experimental. Only after additional quality control is data released as the final product. That process takes about 3 months so all data that is younger than 3 months is ERA5T. When you have a data set with a time series that straddles this 3-month boundary you get an additional dimension, `expver`, with dimension values 1 (final product, the older data) and 5 (the experimental recent data). That arrangement is explained in more detail [here](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/CUSF/ERA5+CDS+requests+which+return+a+mixture+of+ERA5+and+ERA5T+data). If you want to blend this data, which is perfectly fine for many applications, you can do so with some effort. The 3D arrays with the two `expver` values are complementary: where one has values, the other `NA` values. There is no specific information in the file that indicates how many valid time steps there are in each `expver` array but you can simply read the data, then drop the slices in the "time" dimension that are all `NA` values and `abind::abind()` the remaining data.

Secondly, your picture is not at all weird and there are no `NA` values in funny places. You have ERA5land data so there is data on all land areas and `NA`s on oceans. Where things go wrong is how you map the data. Your image is obviously mirrored, with Bretagne pointing upwards, the Alps over the Pyrenees and vice-versa. The "culprit" here is that R organises its data in column-major order (from the top-left corner values progress downwards and then by column to the right) (reading chapter 5 in the R Manual would give you all the details), while typical mapping software uses a row-major order (from the top-left corner work across, then down). If you pass `raster::raster()` an NetCDF file it will interpret this correctly but if you give it an array it has no way of knowing if the data has been corrected for this difference in storage. You can easily correct this by permutating the 3D array (so after merging the two `expver` slices) with `aperm(., c(2, 1, 3))`.

Comment: From which I learned a thing or three, very useful.